# Downloading an Image via ImageLoader

Tags: android

I'm attempting to use ImageLoader to get the two images below and I'm getting an EACCES (Permission denied). Did I miss something?

In my manifest I have:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

urls:
`http://projectcaruso.com/android/com.projectcaruso/idea/dumpfolder/345
http://projectcaruso.com/android/com.projectcaruso/idea/dumpfolder/342`

I'm calling it as:

`LocalImageLoader imageLoader=new LocalImageLoader(FeedActivity.this);
imageLoader.DisplayImage(URL, image);`

```
02-14 13:39:51.270: W/System.err(9446): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/LazyList/-649435551: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
02-14 13:39:51.270: W/System.err(9446):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
02-14 13:39:51.270: W/System.err(9446):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
02-14 13:39:51.270: W/System.err(9446):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:73)
02-14 13:39:51.270: W/System.err(9446):     at com.projectCaruso.idea.LocalImageLoader.getBitmap(LocalImageLoader.java:72)
02-14 13:39:51.270: W/System.err(9446):     at com.projectCaruso.idea.LocalImageLoader.access$0(LocalImageLoader.java:54)
02-14 13:39:51.270: W/System.err(9446):     at com.projectCaruso.idea.LocalImageLoader$PhotosLoader.run(LocalImageLoader.java:132)
02-14 13:39:51.270: W/System.err(9446):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:390)
02-14 13:39:51.270: W/System.err(9446):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-14 13:39:51.270: W/System.err(9446):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-14 13:39:51.270: W/System.err(9446):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-14 13:39:51.270: W/System.err(9446):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
02-14 13:39:51.270: W/System.err(9446): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
02-14 13:39:51.270: W/System.err(9446):     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
02-14 13:39:51.270: W/System.err(9446):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
02-14 13:39:51.270: W/System.err(9446):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:393)
02-14 13:39:51.270: W/System.err(9446):     ... 10 more
02-14 13:39:51.290: W/System.err(9446): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/LazyList/-649435554: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
02-14 13:39:51.290: W/System.err(9446):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
02-14 13:39:51.290: W/System.err(9446):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
02-14 13:39:51.290: W/System.err(9446):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:73)
02-14 13:39:51.290: W/System.err(9446):     at com.projectCaruso.idea.LocalImageLoader.getBitmap(LocalImageLoader.java:72)
02-14 13:39:51.290: W/System.err(9446):     at com.projectCaruso.idea.LocalImageLoader.access$0(LocalImageLoader.java:54)
02-14 13:39:51.290: W/System.err(9446):     at com.projectCaruso.idea.LocalImageLoader$PhotosLoader.run(LocalImageLoader.java:132)
02-14 13:39:51.300: W/System.err(9446):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:390)
02-14 13:39:51.300: W/System.err(9446):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-14 13:39:51.300: W/System.err(9446):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-14 13:39:51.300: W/System.err(9446):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-14 13:39:51.300: W/System.err(9446):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
02-14 13:39:51.300: W/System.err(9446): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
02-14 13:39:51.300: W/System.err(9446):     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
02-14 13:39:51.300: W/System.err(9446):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
02-14 13:39:51.300: W/System.err(9446):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:393)
02-14 13:39:51.300: W/System.err(9446):     ... 10 more
02-14 13:39:51.310: W/System.err(9446): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/LazyList/-649435551: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
02-14 13:39:51.310: W/System.err(9446):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
02-14 13:39:51.310: W/System.err(9446):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
02-14 13:39:51.310: W/System.err(9446):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:73)
02-14 13:39:51.310: W/System.err(9446):     at com.projectCaruso.idea.LocalImageLoader.getBitmap(LocalImageLoader.java:72)
02-14 13:39:51.310: W/System.err(9446):     at com.projectCaruso.idea.LocalImageLoader.access$0(LocalImageLoader.java:54)
02-14 13:39:51.310: W/System.err(9446):     at com.projectCaruso.idea.LocalImageLoader$PhotosLoader.run(LocalImageLoader.java:132)
02-14 13:39:51.310: W/System.err(9446):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:390)
02-14 13:39:51.310: W/System.err(9446):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-14 13:39:51.310: W/System.err(9446):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-14 13:39:51.310: W/System.err(9446):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-14 13:39:51.310: W/System.err(9446):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
02-14 13:39:51.310: W/System.err(9446): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
02-14 13:39:51.310: W/System.err(9446):     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
02-14 13:39:51.310: W/System.err(9446):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
02-14 13:39:51.310: W/System.err(9446):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:393)
02-14 13:39:51.310: W/System.err(9446):     ... 10 more
02-14 13:39:51.361: W/System.err(9446): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/LazyList/-649435554: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
02-14 13:39:51.361: W/System.err(9446):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
02-14 13:39:51.361: W/System.err(9446):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
02-14 13:39:51.361: W/System.err(9446):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:73)
02-14 13:39:51.361: W/System.err(9446):     at com.projectCaruso.idea.LocalImageLoader.getBitmap(LocalImageLoader.java:72)
02-14 13:39:51.361: W/System.err(9446):     at com.projectCaruso.idea.LocalImageLoader.access$0(LocalImageLoader.java:54)
02-14 13:39:51.361: W/System.err(9446):     at com.projectCaruso.idea.LocalImageLoader$PhotosLoader.run(LocalImageLoader.java:132)
02-14 13:39:51.361: W/System.err(9446):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:390)
02-14 13:39:51.361: W/System.err(9446):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-14 13:39:51.361: W/System.err(9446):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-14 13:39:51.361: W/System.err(9446):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-14 13:39:51.361: W/System.err(9446):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
02-14 13:39:51.361: W/System.err(9446): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
02-14 13:39:51.361: W/System.err(9446):     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
02-14 13:39:51.361: W/System.err(9446):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
02-14 13:39:51.361: W/System.err(9446):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:393)
02-14 13:39:51.361: W/System.err(9446):     ... 10 more
02-14 13:39:51.631: W/System.err(9446): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/LazyList/-649435551: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
02-14 13:39:51.631: W/System.err(9446):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
02-14 13:39:51.631: W/System.err(9446):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
02-14 13:39:51.631: W/System.err(9446):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:73)
02-14 13:39:51.631: W/System.err(9446):     at com.projectCaruso.idea.LocalImageLoader.getBitmap(LocalImageLoader.java:72)
02-14 13:39:51.631: W/System.err(9446):     at com.projectCaruso.idea.LocalImageLoader.access$0(LocalImageLoader.java:54)
02-14 13:39:51.631: W/System.err(9446):     at com.projectCaruso.idea.LocalImageLoader$PhotosLoader.run(LocalImageLoader.java:132)
02-14 13:39:51.631: W/System.err(9446):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:390)
02-14 13:39:51.631: W/System.err(9446):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-14 13:39:51.631: W/System.err(9446):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-14 13:39:51.631: W/System.err(9446):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-14 13:39:51.631: W/System.err(9446):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
02-14 13:39:51.631: W/System.err(9446): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
02-14 13:39:51.631: W/System.err(9446): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/LazyList/-649435554: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
02-14 13:39:51.631: W/System.err(9446):     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
02-14 13:39:51.631: W/System.err(9446):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
02-14 13:39:51.641: W/System.err(9446):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:393)
02-14 13:39:51.641: W/System.err(9446):     ... 10 more
02-14 13:39:51.641: W/System.err(9446): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/LazyList/-649435554: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
02-14 13:39:51.641: W/System.err(9446):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/LazyList/-649435551: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
02-14 13:39:51.641: W/System.err(9446):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
02-14 13:39:51.641: W/System.err(9446):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
02-14 13:39:51.641: W/System.err(9446):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:73)
02-14 13:39:51.641: W/System.err(9446):     at com.projectCaruso.idea.LocalImageLoader.getBitmap(LocalImageLoader.java:72)
02-14 13:39:51.641: W/System.err(9446):     at com.projectCaruso.idea.LocalImageLoader.access$0(LocalImageLoader.java:54)
02-14 13:39:51.641: W/System.err(9446):     at com.projectCaruso.idea.LocalImageLoader$PhotosLoader.run(LocalImageLoader.java:132)
02-14 13:39:51.641: W/System.err(9446):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:390)
02-14 13:39:51.641: W/System.err(9446):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-14 13:39:51.641: W/System.err(9446):     at  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
02-14 13:39:51.641: W/System.err(9446):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
02-14 13:39:51.641: W/System.err(9446):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:73)
02-14 13:39:51.641: W/System.err(9446):     at com.projectCaruso.idea.LocalImageLoader.getBitmap(LocalImageLoader.java:72)
02-14 13:39:51.641: W/System.err(9446):     at com.projectCaruso.idea.LocalImageLoader.access$0(LocalImageLoader.java:54)
02-14 13:39:51.641: W/System.err(9446):     at com.projectCaruso.idea.LocalImageLoader$PhotosLoader.run(LocalImageLoader.java:132)
02-14 13:39:51.641: W/System.err(9446):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:390)
02-14 13:39:51.641: W/System.err(9446):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-14 13:39:51.641: W/System.err(9446):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-14 13:39:51.641: W/System.err(9446):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-14 13:39:51.641: W/System.err(9446):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
02-14 13:39:51.641: W/System.err(9446): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
02-14 13:39:51.641: W/System.err(9446):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-14 13:39:51.641: W/System.err(9446):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
02-14 13:39:51.641: W/System.err(9446): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
02-14 13:39:51.641: W/System.err(9446):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
02-14 13:39:51.641: W/System.err(9446):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:73)
02-14 13:39:51.651: W/System.err(9446):     at  at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
02-14 13:39:51.651: W/System.err(9446):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
02-14 13:39:51.651: W/System.err(9446):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:393)
02-14 13:39:51.651: W/System.err(9446):     ... 10 more
02-14 13:39:51.651: W/System.err(9446):     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
02-14 13:39:51.651: W/System.err(9446):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
02-14 13:39:51.651: W/System.err(9446):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:393)
02-14 13:39:51.651: W/System.err(9446):     ... 10 more
02-14 13:39:51.651: W/System.err(9446): com.projectCaruso.idea.LocalImageLoader.getBitmap(LocalImageLoader.java:72)
02-14 13:39:51.651: W/System.err(9446):     at com.projectCaruso.idea.LocalImageLoader.access$0(LocalImageLoader.java:54)
02-14 13:39:51.651: W/System.err(9446):     at com.projectCaruso.idea.LocalImageLoader$PhotosLoader.run(LocalImageLoader.java:132)
02-14 13:39:51.651: W/System.err(9446):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:390)
02-14 13:39:51.651: W/System.err(9446):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-14 13:39:51.651: W/System.err(9446):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-14 13:39:51.651: W/System.err(9446):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-14 13:39:51.651: W/System.err(9446):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
02-14 13:39:51.651: W/System.err(9446): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
02-14 13:39:51.651: W/System.err(9446):     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
02-14 13:39:51.651: W/System.err(9446):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
02-14 13:39:51.651: W/System.err(9446):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:393)
02-14 13:39:51.651: W/System.err(9446):     ... 10 more
```

Comment: u need write permission for your storage..  the image loader is trying to cache it in disk (2nd level cache).. since you don't have permissions to write it ends up in FileNotFoundException

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation of why it happened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

since you are getting this message

```
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/LazyList/-649435551: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Do you have?

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: I did not! Your my best fried now! Thanks for the help